# How to solve "expected struct, found type parameter" on assignment?

Tags: rust

Just started working with Rust a couple of days ago.  I'm porting some C++ code right now, and this question seems to be the reverse of the common "expected struct, got type" sort.    This code involves two classes, a container class A and a client class B.

```
use std::vec::Vec;

struct  A<T:FooTrait> {
    children: Vec<*mut T>
}

impl <T:FooTrait> A<T> {
    fn insert(&mut self, val: &mut T) -> Handle<T> {
        self.children.push(val);
        return Handle{owner: self};
    }
}
struct B {
    handle: Handle<B>
}

trait FooTrait {
    fn set_handle<T:FooTrait>(&mut self, h: Handle<T>);
}

impl FooTrait for B {
    fn set_handle<B:FooTrait>(&mut self, h: Handle<B>) {
        self.handle = h;  // <-- Here is the problem
    }
}

struct  Handle<T:FooTrait> {
    owner: *mut A<T>
}

impl <T:FooTrait> Default for Handle<T> {
    fn default()->Handle<T> {
        Handle {
            owner: std::ptr::null_mut()
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut foo =  A::<B> { children: Default::default() };
    let mut b = B{handle: Default::default()};
    b.handle = foo.insert(&mut b);
}
```

Getting the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:23
   |
22 |     fn set_handle<B:FooTrait>(&mut self, h: Handle<B>) {
   |                   - this type parameter
23 |         self.handle = h;
   |                       ^ expected struct `B`, found type parameter `B`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Handle<B>` (struct `B`)
              found struct `Handle<B>` (type parameter `B`)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplified version [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0b719aaf3a9d777d35923dd739851976):

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct B {
    handle: PhantomData<B>,
}

trait FooTrait {
    fn set_handle<T: FooTrait>(&mut self, h: PhantomData<T>);
}

impl FooTrait for B {
    fn set_handle<BType: FooTrait>(&mut self, h: PhantomData<BType>) {
        self.handle = h;
    }
}
```

Note that I've changed the name of the type parameter in `set_handle`. Now the error is more clear:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:23
   |
12 |     fn set_handle<BType: FooTrait>(&mut self, h: PhantomData<BType>) {
   |                   ----- this type parameter
13 |         self.handle = h;
   |                       ^ expected struct `B`, found type parameter `BType`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::marker::PhantomData<B>`
              found struct `std::marker::PhantomData<BType>`
```

In your case, the error is essentially the same, since the generic parameter is a new type, which shadowed the global `struct B`.

Now, what to do? It depends on what do you want to get.

- If the `struct B` definition is correct and `set_handle` need to handle only `B`s, just remove the generic parameter from `set_handle` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae0cf2808272b74c7365e5fd54e286b4)):

```
trait FooTrait {
    fn set_handle(&mut self, h: PhantomData<B>);
}

impl FooTrait for B {
    fn set_handle(&mut self, h: PhantomData<B>) {
        self.handle = h;
    }
}
```

- If the `struct B` definition is correct, but `set_handle` must be able to use different handler types depending on `Self`, use an associated type ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae0cf2808272b74c7365e5fd54e286b4)):

```
trait FooTrait {
    type T: FooTrait;
    fn set_handle(&mut self, h: PhantomData<Self::T>);
}

impl FooTrait for B {
    type T = B;
    fn set_handle(&mut self, h: PhantomData<B>) {
        self.handle = h;
    }
}
```

Now the implementation block will choose what kind of argument (handler, in your case) it will get.

- If the `set_handle` definition is correct, i.e. the caller can choose the type of handler, then `struct B` must be generic, too. However, in this case you essentially can't use the trait-based approach, since the trait has to be generic too, and you will not be able to simply use it in any generic bound without providing parameters (which has to be bound too, ad infinitum).

Comment: Thank you!  I got pretty close to this at one point but was missing the :FooTrait; on typeT:FooTrait;  That was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different `B` here.  The original `B` you defined in `struct B`, and the second `<B:FooTrait>` type parameter.  The second is shadowing the first.  Here is how the compiler sees it:

```
impl FooTrait for B {
    fn set_handle<AnyFoo:FooTrait>(&mut self, h: Handle<AnyFoo>) {
        self.handle = h;  // <-- Here is the problem
    }
}
```

The way you've defined things, `FooTrait::set_handle` is supposed to work with any type that implements `FooTrait`, but the handle field of `B` can only store a `Handle<B>`.  You need to rethink what you want `FooTrait` to do and how `B` satisfies it.